# "csr contains no data" when signing CSR on a local instance of Vault on a windows machine

Tags: hashicorp-vault, pki, ca

I'm trying to sign an ICA with Vault following [this tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/secrets-management/pki-engine)
And I am the stage where I'm signing the intermediate and I keep getting a "csr contains no data" error, I tried @file, I also tried getting the file contents on a variable and even in-lining the entire file, someone mentioned backticks and online but it doesn't read it properly on the powershell terminal
here is the command I'm using

```
vault write -format=json rootCA/root/sign-intermediate `
>> issuer_ref="root" `
>> csr=@nt.csr `
>> format=pem_bundle ttl="43800h" `
>> | jq -r ".data.certificate" > int.cert.pem
```

and the full error

```
Error writing data to rootCA/root/sign-intermediate: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://localhost:8200/v1/rootCA/root/sign-intermediate
Code: 400. Errors:

* csr contains no data
```

EDIT: I used wireshark to investigate the message and if I am using the @ notation then I send it with \u0000 between each character...
but if I inline it, it seems fine and yet I still get the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inlined the CSR again, but this time ensuring to keep the new lines...
This worked